# Javascript - printing object keys to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, object, innerhtml

So I'm trying to print out each category of items that my store object sells to an HTML file in Javascript. When I attempted to do so below, it doesn't seem to print anything and I was wondering if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I want it to print out:

Ice cream

Cake

```
let dessert = {
    store: "Baskin Robbins",
    inventory: {
        "Ice cream": {
            0: {
                flavor: "Chocolate",
                cost: 15
            },
            1: { 
                flavor: "Vanilla",
                cost: 10
            }
        },
        "Cake": {
            2: {
                flavor: "Oreo",
                cost: 30
            }
        }
    }
};



function showCategories(){
    let userPicked = document.getElementById("list").value;
    var div = document.getElementById("div");   
    if(userPicked == 'dessert'){
        var categories = "Inventory";
        categories += "<br>";
        var options = Object.keys(dessert.inventory);
        categories += options;
        div.innerHTML = categories;
    }

}
```

also my html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><h1>Welcome</h1></div><br />
    <div class="dropdown">
        <form>
        <select name="list" id="list" accesskey="target">
            <option value="none">Pick store</option>
            <option value="one">Desserts</option> 
        </select>
        <input type=button value="Select" onclick="showOptions()" onclick = "showCategories()"/>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div"></div>
        <script src="store.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns an array. You can iterate the array to build a new string, or simply join it:

`categories += options.join('<br>')`

There are a few errors in your code that are preventing this from working:

1. Only have one onclick attribute on your button: `onclick="showCategories()"`
2. The option value for Desserts needs to match your if statement in showCategories. So either change the if condition to `userPicked === 'one'`, or change the Desserts option value to `<option value="dessert">Desserts</option>`

Comment: Hi! the onclick = "showOptions()" displays another body of info that I need to show up when the user clicks the button. I also need "showCategories()" to show up as well, is there a way for both to show up at the same time?

Comment: @Grayish You can only have one onclick attribute per element. You could use a separate function that calls both `showOptions` and `showCategories`. If you want to attach multiple event listeners, you must use `addEventListener` instead of the onclick attribute. Using addEventListener is generally preferred — use of the onclick attribute is generally considered bad practice (but nothing wrong with it for simple proof of concept stuff).

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to your dropdown options and filter your menu options with the selected value. Then, it's just a matter of building up your elements and appending them to the list.

```js
const dessert = {
    store: "Baskin Robbins",
    inventory: {
        "Ice cream": {
            0: {
                flavor: "Chocolate",
                cost: 15
            },
            1: { 
                flavor: "Vanilla",
                cost: 10
            }
        },
        "Cake": {
            2: {
                flavor: "Oreo",
                cost: 30
            }
        }
    }
};
const ddl = document.getElementById('ddl');
ddl.addEventListener('change', e => {
  const itemsList = document.getElementById('items');
  itemsList.innerHTML = '';
  const options = dessert.inventory[e.target.value];
  for (const key in options) {
    const flavor = options[key].flavor;
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerText = flavor;
    itemsList.append(div);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<select id="ddl">
  <option>Select...</option>
  <option value="Ice cream">Ice Cream</option>
  <option value="Cake">Cake</option>
</select>

<div id="items"></div>
```